# "Server has gone away" after migration / upgrade to XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

I'm getting multiple errors after migrating my MySQL database. I've actually moved:

- from desktop to a new laptop
- from Windows 7 to Windows 10
- from standalone Apache / MySQL / PHP to XAMPP...
- ...so I've also moved from MySQL to MariaDB.

I migrated the database with MYSQL_DUMP and brought in with phpMyAdmin and MYSQL_UPGRADE. Everything works fine in phpMyAdmin - all schemas, databases, fields, data etc intact - but when I run any kind of SQL query it falls over.

Error messages I'm getting:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=6908 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php on line 5

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php on line 5
```

The script which produces this error is:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost:8080", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();

} else 

echo "worked";

?>
```

The only coding difference from the previous installation is the introduction of 8080 due to a conflict on the Apache port - everything (including much more complicated queries, honest!) worked perfectly before moving everything across.

I've googled a LOT (not just this site) and tried a few tweaks to my.ini - so far they've just made the error slower to appear! Very happy to test more though.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks all, John.

Comment: What do you get from `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VALUE = 30;` ?

Comment: 8080??  That is usually an alternative for 80.  MySQL's default port is 3306.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your response. Second one first: I've taken out the 8080 and had hoped that it would be a "D'oh!" moment and everything would work - however, I now have an error as follows: 

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test.php on line 5
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Have I made things better or worse?! Thank you!

Comment: Things are better -- you are now connecting, but being denied access.  Perhaps bad GRANT, perhaps bad pwd, perhaps...

Comment: Connect as `root` and do `SHOW GRANTS FOR xxxxx@localhost;`.  (Mask out the encrypted password.)

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I ran this on phpMyAdmin and got the following error: #1141 - There is no such grant defined for user 'xxxxx' on host 'localhost'. Progress...?

Comment: But, when I use wildcard i.e.  `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'xxxx'@'%';`, it's giving me `Grants for xxxxx@% 

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, FILE ON *.* ...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'xxxx...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` in not included in `%`.  Add a similar `GRANT ... TO xxxxx@localhost ...;`

Comment: Sir, thank you again for your patience - you've solved it and I'm hugely appreciative. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get following error or problem then follow above solution.

**Error:**
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=3528
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

**Solution 1:**
use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Don't use any port number after 127.0.0.1.

**Solution 2:**
Check your host file located at
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**
and remove any localhost or 127.0.0.1 entry in file and save.
 You can use any HostEditor program to edit this file.